# com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1 issue

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

I just created an Android project using Android Studio (v3.1.4) which consists of 1 activity: LoginActivity (generated from wizard).

Here's the content of my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.anta40.com.home_client_app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I'd like to use Firebase Database, so I added this line on build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Then Android Studio red-underlined the appcompat-v7 part, saying:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0-rc01, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc01 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).

How to solve this?

Comment: Would you please try to use target and compile SDK 27 and use appcompact-v7 and design version 27.1.1

Answer (score 0):

There are incompatibility issues between your app compat which is: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01' and firebase database version which is: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'.
One solution for this would be to use a lower targetsdk version like 27 and app compat, for example

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: This worked for me. I changed my target sdk to 27 and used the same firebase-database:16.0.1 and it fixed my app problems.